# How to pass parameters to a javascript file called in Vaadin?

Tags: javascript, vaadin23

I am successully calling a javascript within Vaadin.  However how could we pass some parameters to this javascript file.

E.g: below I pass the variable *num*  to the JS file but it does not work.

JAVA:

```
Div myDiv = new Div();
int num = 1000;
UI.getCurrent().getPage().addJavaScript("src/functparam.js", LoadMode.LAZY);
add(myDiv);
```

JS file content (functparam.js):

```
alert('This is a number: ' + num);
```

Comment: How would you pass the parameter to that file in JavaScript?

Comment: @ollitietavainen that is the question that I have asked and want to know how to achieve it.

Comment: When you load a script file, the code inside it gets parsed and executed. You can't pass a parameter to a file from JavaScript, because the file itself is not an entity JavaScript understands. What you might do is create a _function_ that accepts parameters; this function will be stored in the browser's memory and it can be invoked once or many times.

Answer (score 0):

use GraalVM. The reason is that it enable JS-Java interoperability.
you have to download the graalVM via adding as dependency in maven (that's if you use maven build).
Then do something like the following to use it:

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new 
ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
Bindings bindings = scriptEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("polyglot.js.allowHostAccess", true);
bindings.put("polyglot.js.allowHostClassLookup", (Predicate<String>) 
YourClass -> true);

scriptEngine.eval("print('hello world')");
scriptEngine.eval("var page = Packages.YourPackage(e.g.: 
com.payments.weeklypayments).YourClass;"+ "print('hello world')");
```

For external js file:

```
scriptEngine.eval(new FileReader("src/functparam.js""));
```

Then in the 'functparam.js', do something like the following:

```
var  sumOfTwoNumbers = function(){
var variableName = Packages.com.payments.weeklypayments.YourClass;
     print('summing method from java: '+ variableName.summing());
}
```

Meanwhile, in YourClass.java, you should have a method 'summing()'

```
@HostAccess.Export
public static int summing(){
    return 112;
}
```

So, to pass in parameters: you can add params into the method like
the following:

```
@HostAccess.Export
public static int summing(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

And then, from 'functparam.js', do something like the following:

```
var  sumOfTwoNumbers = function(){
var variableName = 
Packages.com.payments.weeklypayments.YourClass;
print ('summing method from java: '+ variableName.summing(3+7));
}
```